# Hide Safari address bar and footer

Tags: jquery-mobile, safari, viewport

On my jQuery Mobile project I'm using the following code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

I'm getting the Safari browser address bar and nav footer. How can I hide those so I can just have my app showing?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can setup a few meta tags to tell iOS that your site can be added to the Home Screen as a web app. Once launched from there, all of the Safari elements are hidden.

Check out the section titled "Hiding Safari User Interface Components" [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/configuringwebapplications/configuringwebapplications.html).

You can specify start up splash screen images and custom icons for the app as it appears on the home screen.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="apple-touch-startup-image-320x460.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="768x1004" href="apple-touch-startup-image-768x1004.png" />
```

Comment: +1.  I would upvote you more if it was allowed : )  This saved me a lot of time. thx

Comment: Ah, the key is that it needs to launched from home screen in order to hide Safari elements. I was testing it from within Safari and couldn't get it to hide the address bar and footer all the time.

Comment: It is working fine but when I open new page using a tags, it shows up web app in new page in safari and address bar shows up again. Do you know why this happens?

Answer (score 3):

You should not need a `<meta>` tag. jQuery mobile should take care of hiding the address bar on iOS. Never been able to get the nav footer disappear myself.

Comment: I know that Sencha Touch hides them very well. I hope I can find a solution to get rid of both.

Comment: Also, your meta tag is missing height. According to this link http://forum.jquery.com/topic/iphone-safari-address-bar-jumps-down-after-page-transition  this is what you might be trying to do <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,height=device-height,width=device-width,user-scalable = no">

Comment: Tried that be I lost my header toolbar :o/

Answer (score 0):

Rob,
try adding below script. This should do the trick of opening new request in the same window

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i].className.match("noeffect")) {
                // Does nothing
            }
            else {
                a[i].onclick = function () {
                    window.location = this.getAttribute("href");
                    return false;
                };
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: You should use jQuery since the OP is using it!