# jQuery mobile pages super large in Safari mobile

Tags: iphone, safari, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to fix a display issue on my jQuery mobile site.  It looks great in other browsers but when viewed on the iPhone in Safari, everything is super large and you cannot shrink the page with pinch.

For example a simple h2 element takes up most of the screen.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; 
          height=device-height; user-scalable=no" />
```

```
    <title>Start</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height; user-scalable=yes" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/android.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />

    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAApPeof0WyN6ORT7NeNop5OxQhS8mdepxW5-6qUjpskYmhafYcLRQjyW8D0bRdsydbD1maEkV9aSDKrw" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Check for iPhone screen size
    if($.mobile.media("screen and (min-width: 320px)")) {
        // Check for iPhone4 Retina Display
        if($.mobile.media("screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)")) {
            $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=device-width, user-scalable=no,initial-scale=.5, maximum-scale=.5, minimum-scale=.5');
        }
    }

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="start">

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">

            <h1>Start</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->          

        <div data-role="content" id="content">  
            <h2>Adventure with:</h2>
            <div id="buttons">

                <a href="/mobile/char/ahBkMjBtLW1vcm5pbmdzdGFycg8" data-role="button" target="_blank">Spam Master</a>                   

                <a href="/mobile/char/create" data-role="button" target="_blank">CREATE NEW FOO</a>         
            </div><!-- /buttons -->
        </div><!-- /content -->

    </div><!-- /page -->    

</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there.
Try setting the initial-scale, that should do the trick.

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=default-width, initial-scale=1" />`

Answer (score 0):

Related:

- [jQueryMobile viewport not working in Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229223/jquerymobile-viewport-not-working-in-windows-phone)
- [changing viewport based on device resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216409/changing-viewport-based-on-device-resolution)
- [Hide Safari address bar and footer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767565/jquery-mobile-viewport-hide-safari-header-and-footer)
- [jquerymobile and screen resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781117/jquerymobile-and-screen-resizing)
- [Is it possible to use jQuery to read meta tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036351/is-it-possible-to-use-jquery-to-read-meta-tags)
- [Having trouble using jQuery to set meta tag values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831529/having-trouble-using-jquery-to-set-meta-tag-values)

Yeah I know there is some reading to do ;)

To enable pinch: `user-scalable=yes`

Comment: I must have another issue.  Neither changing the meta tag or user-scalable has any effect on the way the site looks in Safari.

Comment: Updated.  There's really nothing to it . . . looks great on FF on Android.

Comment: what type of iPhone are you testing on? this line stands out for me: $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content','width=device-width, user-scalable=no,initial-scale=.5, maximum-scale=.5, minimum-scale=.5');